# What is difference between jquery.js and jquery.lite.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I download the jQuery zip file [LINK](http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.5-release.zip). It gives me 4 different files:

- jquery.js
- jquery.lite.js
- jquery.min.js
- jquery.pack.js

`pack.js` is the most compressed one of that js file and `min` is minified.
So I have two questions...

1. What is difference between `jquery.js` and `jquery.lite.js`. There looks to be no difference when I view code.
2. What is better to use `min.js` or `pack.js` on a live website?

Comment: Did you consider a diff or the docs?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release ;)

Comment: Guys, Actually I am using newer only V 1.8, but when I was googling for min and pack for jquery, I found repository of it, which comes with question mark `(?)`. Why 4 different files are there???

Comment: @SLaks +1 from my side to balance unfair -4. Reason: Even I never heard about jquery.lite.js and jquery.pack.js but they existed in past. We can't expect everyone is old man in tech. So if someone come to know about past solutions, they could be interested to know about them. They could ask such straight forward question. I don't see anything wrong in it.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Please check previous comment.

Comment: @DaveNewton Please check previous comment

Comment: @KapilSharma Thanks actually I am also not using this older version. That's just a question to know history ;)

Comment: +1 I am also hearing about jquery.lite.js for the first time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Answer to the question:**

**jquery.js** - Full expanded including comments.

**jquery.lite.js** - Not really relevant anymore - new releases don't give this - it mainly used to lack comments and less used features.

**jquery.min.js** - The main one to use nowadays - all whitespace and comments removed.

**jquery.pack.js** - Smaller in size - but requires 'unpacking' time, sort of like a rar/zip would.

But honestly, as others have mentioned use the [latest release](http://jquery.com/download/) of jQuery if possible.

-

**Updated information for 2018**:

**Compressed production** - Removal and minification of code, no spaces/line breaks, hard for humans to read but smaller in size so it loads faster.

**Uncompressed production** - Larger file size, easier for developers to work on but shouldn't be used in production due to unnecessary file size.

**Map file** - Helps developers/web browsers find references to the original location of JS code before it was compressed.

**Slim builds** - This version of jQuery doesn't include a few larger libraries, such as the AJAX and effects modules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it's older version, even I am not going to use it. That's just question to know what was it...

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a CDN, use Microsoft or Google cdn:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

or

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0

Use the latest version, the `.lite.js` is not an official jQuery version, same for the `.pack.js`.

On the jQuery website you can only find Production (Minified) or Development (not Minified) versions.

Here: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery you'll find all the official information about versions of jQuery.