# How can I use Angular jqLite (angular.element) independently?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm seeking a simple wrapper for DOM. There are many choice like Zepto, jQLite and so on. For me, [Angular jqLite](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js) is seems to be well wrapped and well maintained.

But actually I can't use jqLite independently because it heavily depends on Angular.js. Is there any way to use it independently? or any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264504/what-is-difference-between-jquery-js-and-jquery-lite-js

Comment: @RodHartzell Absolutely no link with the question. Kechol, You mean you don't want to include all the AngularJS framework just to use the jqLite part? I think you've no choice, sadly.

Comment: You can try to include just [the jqLite part](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js) and see if you get any error. It's absolutely possible that jqLite is totally set apart of AngularJS.

Comment: Already I did and I got jqLite is using functions from [Angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js).

Comment: @Blackhole The link I referenced is related to the question.  Since it was clearly tldr; I will simplify: jQuery is lite enough as is.